# Windows 10 Show recently opened items in task bar but not anywhere else

Tags: windows-10

Since the Windows 10 update a few months back, the option to view recent items is now combined for Taskbar and Quick access, the option being "Show recent opened items in Jump Lists on Start or the taskbar". Prior to the update, I could select them individually (don't remember the option though).

Is there any way, maybe through registry, that I can keep recent opened items in taskbar (right clicking any program in taskbar) but not in 'Recent Files' in Quick Access (File Explorer)?

Comment: Have you already tried to navigate through `File Explorer > View tab > Options > Folder Options > General tab` and unchecked `Show recently used files in Quick access`?  On my machine, that seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way, maybe through registry, that I can keep recent opened items in taskbar (right clicking any program in taskbar) but not in 'Recent Files' in Quick Access (File Explorer)?

If I am correctly interpreting what you want, you should be able to set this:

[image: Start Settings]

At the same time, you should be able to configure this: open `File Explorer` and navigate through `View tab > Options > Folder Options > General tab`.  Once there, uncheck `Show recently used files in Quick access` accordingly:

[image: Folder Options]

As a side note, if you ever want to check an in-depth list of your Recent Items, you can create a shortcut to `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\`.